# Explanation for (t for t in L if t ) in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

There was an exercise in python to remove an empty tuple(s) from a list of tuples.

The input:

`input: [(), (), ('',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d')]`

The expected output

`output: [('',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), 'd']`

Here is the solution that they have provided.

```
L = [(), (), ('',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d')]
L = [t for t in L if t]
print(L)
```

But i couldn't understand condition  `L = [t for t in L if t]`.  can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What don't you understand? the list comprehension? the `if`?

Comment: If you do `bool(())` or `bool('')`, you will see that empty list and strings return `False`. So the command `if t` basically returns `t` if it returns `True`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples.

Comment: @wwii can you link to specific SO documentation that discourages users to ask about specific lines of codes they don't understand?

Comment: @CorentinPane - I don't think there is any specific prohibition but if you read the entirety of all the the links on the page I linked to you get a sense of it.  Searching on Meta will give you an idea of what the community thinks - although you may find conflicting info there.  Here is a start - read everything linked to and do other searches with similar phrases [“How does this code works” questions (duplicate)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306160/how-does-this-code-works-questions). Not my DV by the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`L = [t for t in L if t]` can be written in pseudo-code like this:

```
result_list = []

for t in L:
  if t is True:
    result_list.append(t)
```

The pseudo code just does not replace the original list, it creates a new one. You also need to know that an empty tuple evaluates to False in Python.